# Как можно добавить внутренний динамический контент виджету в Elementor?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, elementor

Я разрабатываю виджет-обертку, в котором будут находиться какие-то другие виджеты. Подскажите, как и можно ли вообще добавить область в которую можно вставлять другие виджеты (см. скрин)

[image: Нужно чтобы появилась такая область с плюсом]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.